# Swiping on webpage makes browser go to previous page

Tags: html, gallery, lightbox

I'm trying to add swipe functionality to Lightbox2. Everything works, but whenever I swipe back, the browser goes to the previous page (I think it's just a feature on all touchscreen computers).

Here is the script i'm using to capture the swipe

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      $(".lb-container").on("swipeleft",function(){
        $('#lightbox a.lb-next').trigger('click');
      });
      $(".lb-container").on("swiperight",function(){
        $('#lightbox a.lb-prev').trigger('click');
      });
    });
```

Thanks

edit:

I am also getting the following error:

Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

Comment: I am currently working on an implementation for this and have a solution already prototyped.  I would be happy to help you get it going if you want.

Comment: additionally, you can always use touch start, move, and end to events if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`swiperight` and `swipeleft` are not events in jQuery but found in jQuery mobile (unfortunately last updated in 2014). You could add jQuery mobile to your page or use a plugin like [TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) to add swipe direction events.